# How to make popper show the scrollbars when it doesn't fit the viewport?

Tags: javascript, css, popper.js

I have to work with pop-ups containing long lists. If the list gets too long the popper overflows the body. I would like to have the pop-up show the scrollbars instead.

Example:

```html
<body>
  <div class="h-100 d-flex">
    <div id="container" class="mx-auto my-auto bg-grn">
      OOF
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="tooltip" class="bg-blu overflow-auto" style="color: white">
    <!-- Ideally this should overflow -->
    Long content
  </div>
  <!-- But instead the whole body overflows -->
</body>
<script>
const tooltip = document.getElementById('tooltip')
tooltip.innerText += 'Long content'.repeat(450)

const popper = Popper.createPopper(document.getElementById("container"), tooltip, {
placement: 'right-start'
})
</script>
```

View it on [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/raldone01/vb7wnya2/16/). On jsFiddle the console is blocking the x scrollbar but it is there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had forgotten how to do this and rediscovered the community modifier [maxSize](https://popper.js.org/docs/v2/modifiers/community-modifiers/).  Which should do what you want: https://codesandbox.io/s/great-tesla-3roz7?file=/src/index.js:222-229

Note: This code was copied from the codesandbox link above:

```js
const applyMaxSize = {
  name: "applyMaxSize",
  enabled: true,
  phase: "beforeWrite",
  requires: ["maxSize"],
  fn({ state }) {
    const { height } = state.modifiersData.maxSize;
    state.styles.popper.maxHeight = `${height}px`;
  }
};

const reference = document.querySelector("#reference");
const popper = document.querySelector("#popper");

createPopper(reference, popper, {
  modifiers: [maxSize, applyMaxSize]
});
```

Comment: This seems to be exactly what I was looking for. I will make use of it soon.

Answer (score 1):

You need to set the `width` and `height` of the tooltip in order to see the scrollbar. Here's an example:

```css
#tooltip {
  height: 150px;
  max-width: 40vw;
}
```

Updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/k5607b3x/23/).

Comment: Popper positions the toolbar using position-absolute. It uses right: auto; and bottom: auto;. Is there no option to make popper adjust the popup to the max possible size?